# Change Displayed Root of Breadcrumb Trail in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7, breadcrumbs

How can I change the displayed root of my breadcrumb trail at a certain point?

Lets say my breadcrumbs map the solar system. I want my displayed trail to begin with *Solar System* until I get to *USA*, at which point I want *USA* to be the root. So I would have trails like this for other planets/continents/countries:

> Solar System > Jupiter > Big Red Swirl
>
> Solar System > Earth > Australia > Sydney
>
> Solar System > Earth > North America > Canada

But once I get to *USA*, instead of the breadcrumb trail appearing as...

> Solar System > Earth > North America > USA

...I would like USA to become the displayed root

> USA
>
> USA > Ohio
>
> USA > California > San Fransisco

Anyone know how I can implement this, whether Drupal module, Drupal technique, or code in my template.php file?

Here is the code in the php template that creates the breadcrumbs:

```
function cph_main_breadcrumb($variables) {

   $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
   $youAreHere = drupal_get_title();
   $crumbs = ' ';

   if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
      $crumbs = '<ul>';
      foreach($breadcrumb as $value) {
         $crumbs .= '<li>' .$value.'</li>';
      }
      $crumbs .= '<li>' . $youAreHere . '<li></ul>';
   }
   return $crumbs;
}
```

Comment: Is js code acceptable? And if so, you want to hide only the breadcrumb before USA or for any breadcrumb item that has a level of 4 (like USA has here)? Can you give the html code of the breadcrumb?

Comment: I only want to hide the breadcrumbs before USA, none of the other level 4 items.

Im not sure what js code is, the breadcrumbs are created using a php template. I will add the code to my post above

Answer (score 0):

```
function MYTHEME_breadcrumb($variables) {

   $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
   //dpm($breadcrumb);
   $youAreHere = drupal_get_title();
   $crumbs = ' ';

   if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
      $crumbs = '<ul>';
      foreach($breadcrumb as $value) {
        // Add an if statement to check current item
        if($value == '<a href="/MY_PATH_TO_THIS_ITEM">USA</a>') {
          // Reset the list
          $crumbs = '<ul>';
        }
        $crumbs .= '<li>' .$value.'</li>';
      }
      $crumbs .= '<li>' . $youAreHere . '<li></ul>';
   }
   return $crumbs;
}
```

- If the current breadcrumb value is the one for "USA" **reset the breadcrumb** and start it again.
- If you want to find the current item for USA dpm() the $breadcrumb to find out. Notice that if the link to USA change later you have to change it here also...

Comment: @kevin please provide some feedback. If this solved your problem select it as accepted or upvote it.